# Unintsallation Ubuntu

Tags: uninstall

I am new to Ubuntu. i have installed it using windows Ubuntu installer. at first it worked well.but i have committed mistake while working in Quantum espresso software,Linux is required plat form for it. this mistake erased my Ubuntu. while i restart my pc there are two OS option to select one is windows and another one is Ubuntu.
when i tried to boot Ubuntu it shows that Ubuntu is erased. so i installed Ubuntu once more.but now problem is when i restart pc it shows three OS list now these are one windows and two Ubuntu and i can boot both the Ubuntu.

so my question is how to erase old all Ubuntu and install new one

please  help in this reg.,
thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific about the steps you took in the second installation? Did you follow the uninstall instructions (found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation)) before attempting the second installation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the **Terminal** program
2. Enter the command `sudo update-grub` (which will ask for your login password)

This should regenerate the menu configuration file of grub bootloader, and remove the duplicate entry.